# Manual colour scale in faceted ggplot waffle chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, waffle-chart

I am trying to get the same customized colour scale for a faceted waffle chart in R, using package `waffle` from https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle and `ggplot2::facet_wrap`.

Below a reproducible example:

```
foo <- 
  data.frame(Genus = c("Hemipenthes","Thecophora","Cheilosia","Cheilosia","Chrysotoxum","Chrysotoxum","Dasysyrphus","Dasysyrphus","Didea","Episyrphus","Eristalis","Eristalis","Eumerus","Eumerus","Eupeodes","Eupeodes","Helophilus","Megasyrphus","Melanostoma","Meliscaeva","Merodon","Merodon","Myathropa","Neoascia","Parasyrphus","Parasyrphus","Platycheirus","Scaeva","Scaeva","Sphaerophoria","Sphaerophoria","Syrphus","Syrphus","Xanthandrus","Andrena","Apis","Bombus","Bombus","Ceratina","Lasioglossum","Lasioglossum","Sphecodes","Sphecodes","Polistes","Macroglossum","Macroglossum","Polyommatus","Aglais","Argynnis","Lasiommata","Lasiommata","Adscita","Thrips","Thrips"), 
             Ploidy = c("4x","4x","4x","8x","4x","8x","4x","8x","8x","4x","4x","8x","4x","8x","4x","8x","4x","4x","8x","4x","4x","8x","4x","8x","4x","8x","8x","4x","8x","4x","8x","4x","8x","4x","4x","8x","4x","8x","8x","4x","8x","4x","8x","8x","4x","8x","4x","8x","4x","4x","8x","4x","4x","8x"), 
             n = as.numeric(c("2","2","0","0","38","0","2","0","0","0","569","35","0","0","63","8","0","2","3","4","20","1","2","1","17","0","2","9","0","21","4","48","61","1","25","15","0","0","0","38","5","0","0","0","0","0","4","1","0","21","2","1","0","0")), 
             stringsAsFactors = F)
foo$Genus <- factor(foo$Genus, levels = unique(foo$Genus))
foo$Ploidy <- factor(foo$Ploidy, levels = c("4x", "8x"))

bar <- 
  data.frame(Genus = c("Hemipenthes","Thecophora","Cheilosia","Chrysotoxum","Dasysyrphus","Didea","Episyrphus","Eristalis","Eumerus","Eupeodes","Helophilus","Megasyrphus","Melanostoma","Meliscaeva","Merodon","Myathropa","Neoascia","Parasyrphus","Platycheirus","Scaeva","Sphaerophoria","Syrphus","Xanthandrus","Andrena","Apis","Bombus","Ceratina","Lasioglossum","Sphecodes","Polistes","Macroglossum","Polyommatus","Aglais","Argynnis","Lasiommata","Adscita","Thrips"), 
                  colour = c("#F2F5EA","#E6ECD5","#DAE2C0","#CED9AC","#C2CF97","#B5C682","#A9BC6E","#9DB359","#91A944","#85A030","#79961B","#739211","#6E8B10","#69850F","#647E0E","#5F780E","#5A720D","#556B0C","#50650B","#4B5F0B","#46580A","#415209","#3C4C08","#F4C0B7","#E98170","#DE4328","#d92405","#BA1E04","#9B1903","#7C1402","#7897F1","#3563EB","#3563eb","#2C52C3","#23429C","#1A3175","#eac124"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
bar$Genus <- factor(bar$Genus, levels = unique(bar$Genus))
```

The colour palette looks like this:

```
barplot(rep(1, nrow(bar)), col = bar$colour, names.arg = bar$Genus, las = 2, cex.names = .75)
```

[image]

Note that both the order of the values and the levels are the same in both datasets:

```
all(unique(foo$Genus) == unique(bar$Genus))
TRUE
```

I now join the two datasets together:

```
foobar <- plyr::join(foo, bar) # preserves row order
```

Then I plot this using waffle:

```
library(ggplot)
library(waffle)
library(hrbrthemes)
ggplot(foobar, aes(fill = Genus, values = n)) + 
  geom_waffle(colour = "white", n_rows = 20, flip = T) + 
  facet_wrap(.~Ploidy, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = foobar$colour, name = NULL) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x * 20, expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "Roboto Condensed") +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_line()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = T))
```

[image]

However, the colours don't correspond to the assigned fill (`Genus`). 
For instance, the first 4 entries of the legend as plotted (Adscita, Lasiommata, Aglais, Polyommatus) should be shades of blue, not green. Additionally, some levels of `Genus` have been dropped altogether, like Cheilosia, Bombus and Didea. This behaviour persists using other geoms or removing the facet.

The desired result is to have each unique value of the `Genus` variable of the same colour across the two facets, as assigned in the custom palette in `bar` and visualized in the barplot above.

Comment: Hi, I am in fact using the github package from: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle, I shall edit the question to make it more clear. The package takes special aesthetics in place of usual x and y specifications

Comment: Just to add to this, the same undesired behaviour appears also in a more usual ggplot call: 
`ggplot(foobar, aes(x = Genus, fill = Genus, y = n)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(.~Ploidy, ncol = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = foobar$colour, name = NULL)`

Comment: I just tried this: 
`ggplot(foobar, aes(x = Genus, fill = colour, y = log(n))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(.~Ploidy, ncol = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
  # scale_fill_manual(values = foobar$colour, name = NULL)
  scale_fill_identity() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))` 

https://imgur.com/a/Fl3Om9x 

It does seem to solve the ordering problem, but this method is not applicable to the waffle geom, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you want? Using `scale_fill_identity(drop = FALSE)`

generally probably better to just use your variable for aesthetic and then map the colors to it with a named vector in `scale_..._manual`. I have added the named vector  as a label now. `drop = FALSE` to show unused levels

```r
library(ggplot2)
#devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/waffle")
library(waffle)

a <- unique(as.character(foobar$Genus))
names(a) <- unique(foobar$colour)

ggplot(foobar, aes(fill = colour, values = n)) + 
  geom_waffle(colour = "white", n_rows = 20, flip = T) + 
  facet_wrap(.~Ploidy, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = 'legend', labels = a, drop = FALSE) +
  labs(fill = 'Genus') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x * 20, expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is really close to the desired result! Is there a way to match the order of the legend labels to the original order of Genus? Like `levels(bar$Genus)`

Comment: I'd factorise `Genus` and reorder the levels based on the count.

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I haven't been clear: I would like both the data in the plot and the legend to be displayed in the same order as `bar$Genus`, as provided in the initial example. It doesn't look like the data is sorted by count in the plot, and in any case that's not desired. 
I've tried to supply manual `breaks` to `scale_fill_identity` but it doesn't produce a legend anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I found the mistake I was making. Setting the call to `scale_fill_identity(guide = 'legend', labels = a, breaks = bar$colour, drop = FALSE)` did the trick. 
Many thanks for the help Tjebo!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tjebo, I was able to solve the problem. Posting here the result for posterity:

```
ggplot(foobar, aes(fill = colour, values = n)) + 
  geom_waffle(colour = "white", n_rows = 20, flip = T) + 
  facet_wrap(.~Ploidy, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = 'legend', labels = a, breaks = bar$colour, drop = FALSE) +
  labs(fill = 'Genus') +
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_x_discrete() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x * 20, expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "Roboto Condensed") +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_line()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = T))
```

[image]

Now the legend correctly corresponds to the custom palette `bar$colour`, and it's displayed in the same order as the original factor `bar$Genus`.